# check the first login wordpress

Tags: wordpress

I need create something like this:

if is first login show: [something]

if is second login show: [something2]

if is third login show: [something3]

because I need to show different messages inside a post on each time login, is it possible?

Comment: what have you tried so far ?

Comment: I am using Magic Members plugin, but this don't do this messages inside a post. I'm trying to check if is first login but I don't know how to check or if is possible. And if is possible, I will need create a shortcode to test inside the post, for example: 

[is_first_login] do my first message [/is_first_login] this would be great.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This is certainly doable, you could try and track cookies, but that will get really tedious and inaccurate over the long run.

You'll probably want to track & increment a custom User Meta field using the [`update_user_meta()`](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/update_user_meta) function tied to the [`wp_login`](https://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Action_Reference/wp_login) hook which fires after a user logs in.

Also, you'll need to read up on the [`add_shortcode()`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/add_shortcode/) function to output the content you want, but something like this will be more than enough to get you started. It tracks how many times they log in, and anywhere you put `[login_content]` - it will output the appropriate text according to the value of `$login_amount`.

```
add_action( 'wp_login', 'track_user_logins', 10, 2 );
function track_user_logins( $user_login, $user ){
    if( $login_amount = get_user_meta( $user->id, 'login_amount', true ) ){
        // They've Logged In Before, increment existing total by 1
        update_user_meta( $user->id, 'login_amount', ++$login_amount );
    } else {
        // First Login, set it to 1
        update_user_meta( $user->id, 'login_amount', 1 );
    }
}

add_shortcode( 'login_content', 'login_content' );
function login_content( $atts ){
    if( is_user_logged_in() ){
        // Get current total amount of logins (should be at least 1)
        $login_amount = get_user_meta( get_current_user_id(), 'login_amount', true );

        // return content based on how many times they've logged in.
        if( $login_amount == 1 ){
            return 'Welcome, this is your first time here!';
        } else if( $login_amount == 2 ){
            return 'Welcome back, second timer!';
        } else if( $login_amount == 3 ){
            return 'Welcome back, third timer!';
        } else {
            return "Geez, you have logged in a lot, $login_amount times in fact...";
        }
    }
}
```

You should just be able to put this in your `functions.php` file.

Comment: Thank you so much! This is exactly what I'm looking for, works perfectly!!

Comment: Wonderful, I'm glad it helped, and I'm sure it will help other people out there, great question!

Comment: Simple, and concise. I was looking for exactly this same thing